# How to turn on/off classicthesis.sty options, manual bibliography & skipleft in classicthesis v4.6

Tags: lyx, classicthesis

I try to customize classicthesis v4.6. Unfortunately I'm not a firm latex user and thus I use classicthesis for Lyx ...

1. Especially I'm looking for ways to turn on dottedtoc and turn off float per chapter using classicthesis.sty as recommended. However `\DeclareBoolOption[true]{dottedtoc}` and `\DeclareBoolOption[false]{floatperchapter}` seems to have no influence.
2. Furthermore I don't want to use a Bibtex bibliography, i.e. I want to create an average text file instead, which contains my references. Thus, I deleted these lines and added a new chapter, but then no title is created in pdf for this chapter.

```
\defbibheading{bibintoc}[\bibname]{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection
  \manualmark
  \markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{\beforebibskip}}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\tocEntry{#1}}%
  \chapter*{#1}%
}
```

3. Additionally I tried to use leftskip. But it seems to be depreciated in classicthesis, too? How can I still solve this problem? Here is what I tried:

```
\begingroup
  \leftskip
    1.20cm
  {
    Text
  }
\endgroup
```

I'd be very happy if you could help me to solve some of my problems. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. You should not be editing classicthesis.sty. Set these options in classicthesis-config.tex. The pdf file that came with the template explains this well, please read it.
2. Start over with the original template, use Bibliography.lyx and delete what's in it. You'll also need to turn off biblatex in this and the main document settings. Next, in the "standard toolbar" pick Bibliography. This is where you'll add your references, one by one.
3. Not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve.